# iOS: Programmatically Push Segue to Multiple View Controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have **one** original view controller with **four** destination view controllers. I want to be able to **push** segue with a navigation controller to *ALL* of the destination view controllers from the original. I have tried...

```
- (IBAction)notificationsButtonPushed:(id)sender {

    NotificationsViewController *notifications = [[NotificationsViewController alloc]init];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:notifications animated:YES];

}

- (IBAction)messagesButtonPushed:(id)sender {

    MessagesViewController *messages = [[MessagesViewController alloc] init];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:messages animated:YES];

}

- (IBAction)settingsButtonPushed:(id)sender {

      if (canMessage) {

          SettingsViewController *settings = [[SettingsViewController alloc]init];

          [self.navigationController pushViewController:settings animated:YES];
      }

      else {

          NSLog(@"Can't Message");
      }

}

- (IBAction)previewButtonPushed:(id)sender {

    PreviewViewController *preview = [[PreviewViewController alloc]init];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:preview animated:YES];

}
```

and this just gives me an empty view controller without my UI components.

**Note**: I also have tired "initWithNidName:" and passed in the storyboardID of each destination view controller and it gives me Error:

```
'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/B7E025E5-D7D2-4FFD-B49C-E10DF5E94C44/LifePoints.app> (loaded)' with name 'preview'
```

I also have tried... (with storyboard segues set to "Push")

```
    - (IBAction)notificationsButtonPushed:(id)sender {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"notifications" sender:self];

}

- (IBAction)messagesButtonPushed:(id)sender {

    if (canMessage) {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"messages" sender:self];

    }

    else {
        NSLog(@"Can't Message");
    }
}

- (IBAction)settingsButtonPushed:(id)sender {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"settings" sender:self];

}

- (IBAction)previewButtonPushed:(id)sender {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"preview" sender:self];

}
```

Although this does push the destination view controllers onto the screen with the appropriate segue type, it does **not** segue to the correct destination view controller. It only seems to segue to the last attached storyboard segue.

Does anyone know how to correctly apply this and have it behave in the form I am looking for?

**EDIT**

It is important to note I am checking to see if a condition is met the "messagesButtonPushed" method. I am checking to see if user is allowed to message, and if they are, then segue to the VC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any code to implement the basic segues.

In your story board ensure that your original view controller is embedded in a navigation controller  (Select the original View and select Edit->Embed in->Navigation Controller).

Then you can simply control drag from each of your four buttons to  the corresponding destination views, selecting "push" as the segue type.  You can then click on the segue icon between the two views to give each segue an identifier.

You can delete your IBAction methods and any actions on the buttons that link to them.

I suggest you complete a [Storyboard Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) to learn how storyboards and segues work.

If you do want to perform a segue programatically then you can control drag from the yellow view controller icon at the bottom of the view to the destination.  You can then invoke the segue with `performSegueWithIdentifier` as per your second code - In your case your could have two different segues and trigger the store segue or the other one depending on purchase status

Comment: Thank you for your response Paul. I suppose this is my fault for not clarifying an important point. One of my buttons I want to segue only **if** a certain condition is met. So I was going to run an 'if statement' to check if the condition is true, _then_ segue to the destination view controller. Do you know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: You can implement the method shouldPerformSegue:ForIdentifier:  you return a Boolean that indicates whether the segue should proceed. Personally, I prefer to set the enabled state of the button to provide feedback to the user that they can't press the button rather than have them press bit and wonder why nothing is happening

Comment: Or the method might just be shouldPerformSegue - I am on my phone at the moment

Comment: Basically the Button has two ways it can go. First if the user has purchased an in app purchase the button will segue to a screen that allows them to message, and if they haven't bought it yet, I want to prompt them to purchase it. Will this still work in this case? Thank you so much for your time I know what its like typing on a phone.